# How is Redux passing state to mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to understand how React and Redux work, and I was looking at FuelSavingsPage.js from [this example project](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot).  I get where `actions` comes from in `mapDispatchToProps`, but I don't understand how `state` is being passed to `mapStateToProps` or how `dispatch` is being passed to `mapDispatchToProps`.  How is this happening?

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/fuelSavingsActions';
import FuelSavingsForm from '../components/FuelSavingsForm';

export const FuelSavingsPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <FuelSavingsForm
      saveFuelSavings={props.actions.saveFuelSavings}
      calculateFuelSavings={props.actions.calculateFuelSavings}
      fuelSavings={props.fuelSavings}
    />
  );
};

FuelSavingsPage.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fuelSavings: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fuelSavings: state.fuelSavings
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FuelSavingsPage);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The React-Redux `connect` function generates a wrapper component that subscribes to the store.  That wrapper component calls `store.getState()` after each dispatched action, calls the supplied `mapStateToProps` function with the current store state, and if necessary, calls `mapDispatchToProps` with the store's `dispatch` function.

Dan wrote a simplified version of `connect` a while back to illustrate the general approach it uses.  See https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1d19088790e70ac32ea636c025ba424e .

Answer (score 8):

All magic in `connect()` function. This function calls `mapStateToProps` and passes `state` as a prop. The same thing happens with `mapDispatchToProps` and the `dispatch` method. You can imagine this with the following pseudo-code:

```
function connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) {
    mapStateToProps(store.getState()) // just simple callback
    mapDispatchToProps(store.dispatch) // the same
}
```